# Valgrind - adb push failed to copy vgdb

Tags: android, adb, valgrind

I'm trying to install valgrind on my android device, but when i try to execute adb push Inst /
i get an error 

`C:\VmFiles>adb push Inst /
push: Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/vgdb -> /data/local/Inst/bin/vgdb
failed to copy 'Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/vgdb' to '/data/local/Inst/bin/vgdb': N
o such file or directory`

Ofc file vgdb exists in this directory

`C:\VmFiles>ls Inst/data/local/Inst/bin
callgrind_annotate  cg_diff   valgrind            vgdb
callgrind_control   cg_merge  valgrind-di-server
cg_annotate         ms_print  valgrind-listener`

Comment: what is inst is a directory

Comment: Yes, inst is a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some observation i found there is no directory Inst/bin in local 
so first you need to make a directory in /data/local/Inst/bin

and for that you need root access to your device because you cant access /data/ directory without root permissions
then do following steps.

first go to directory where vgdb is placed then
execute

```
adb push vgdb /data/local/Inst/bin/
```

Comment: Ok i did that, but i get the same error `C:\VmFiles\Inst\data\local\Inst\bin>adb push vgdb /data/local/Inst/bin/
failed to copy 'vgdb' to '/data/local/Inst/bin/': No such file or directory`.

Comment: I worked for /data/local/Inst/bin/ but now i got another error `push: Inst/usr/local/bin/vgdb -> /usr/local/bin/vgdb
failed to copy 'Inst/usr/local/bin/vgdb' to '/usr/local/bin/vgdb': No such file or directory` and i can't create it `127|shell@android:/ # mkdir usr
mkdir usr
mkdir failed for usr, Read-only file system`

Comment: ya first you have to root your device then you will be able to make directories

Comment: try at shell--> sh mkdir /data/local/Inst/bin if works?

Comment: I have root, but i can't create usr directory

Comment: try this to check wheater your device is rooted https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en

Comment: I checked and i have root, i also created usr/local/bin directory with Root Browser application, but now when i try to push i get another error `push: Inst/usr/local/bin/vgdb -> /usr/local/bin/vgdb
failed to copy 'Inst/usr/local/bin/vgdb' to '/usr/local/bin/vgdb': Read-only fil
e system` Before that i executed `chmod -R 777 usr` command, so i have no more ideas what can i do with this.

Comment: copy your file by root browser first put your vgdb file in sdcard then open in root browser and copy it and paste at data/local/inst/bin

Comment: and dont mismatch linux and android there is no directory usr/local in android use data/local/

Comment: The premise of this answer is untrue. While you cannot list /data without root, you can still access much of it.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for `adb push` :

```
adb push <PATH_OF_FILE_ON_HOST> <PATH_OF_FILE_ON_DEVICE>`
```

Since you are trying to push from `Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/` path. Use the below command with **absolute** path.

```
adb push /full/path/to/Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/ /path/on/device/test_folder/
```

This should push **all** (both files and directory) content of the directory `Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/` to `/path/on/device/test_folder/`

Make sure `/path/on/device/test_folder/` exist, or run below command before hand.

```
adb shell mkdir /path/on/device/test_folder/
```

Use `adb shell ls /path/on/device/test_folder/` to list, if your files are transferred to the device.

Also make sure you have **permission** to write to `/path/on/device/test_folder`

**Note:** You will usually have permission to write to `/sdcard/` but again will require root permission to assign execute permission (`chmod`) to the transferred binary.
In this case, may need to root the device.

Comment: No, root is not needed for chmod.  However, files on the sdcard are not executable, period.

Comment: If I cross compile (say a `Hello World` program) and build a binary (called `exe`). For a non-rooted device, I could push it to `/sdcard` but cannot run it (Using ./exe from command-line). Since there would be no execute permission. When I run `chmod`. I get `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Nobody can run things from the sdcard as it is mounted noexec.  Use your app's internal storage in a directory you have it grant adb's shell user permission to, or (for experiments only) see if there is something like a /data/local/temp

Comment: On a non-rooted device, I'll never be able to push any data to `/data` since It will throw `Read-only file system`. Exactly why I'm pushing to `/sdcard`. I'm not exactly running an app here. Its just a binary or an ordinary file.

Comment: You cannot push to the top level directory /data, but you can push to a path **within an application's private storage directory under /data to which it has explicitly granted the adb shell user access**.  Even if you make a dummy app *simply for the purpose of having such a container*.  On many current devices, you can also push to /data/local/tmp `touch test ; adb push test /data/local/tmp ; adb shell ls -l  /data/local/tmp`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm away from work. I will surely cross check and get back to you. So after the `push` is successful, `chmod` wouldn't require permission I assume.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, Turns out you were right. As you said, I'm able to push files under `/data/local/tmp` as well as execute `chmod` for non-rooted device. Thanks for this. Learnt something new here.