# Push application-readable file to Android device

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to push a file to an Android device and then read it within a test app. It doesn't particularly matter where the file is, I can hardcode the path in the app, but the file has to be written to the device separately. If I push the file somewhere with `adb`, it's owned by root with permissions 660 and the app can't open it. If I `run-as` the app and try to read the file, I get "Permission denied". If I try to chmod the file I get "Operation not permitted". Is there some way to do this, other than rooting the device?

Comment: Are you sure after pushing the file via adb, the following adb root && adb shell 'chmod 0777 myfile_path' doesn't work ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat `adb root` gives "adbd cannot run as root in production builds". Trying to `chmod` gives "Operation not permitted"

Comment: Have you tried pushing the file to partition mounted on the sdcard ? since you managed pushing files (*w/o* running beforehand adb root) those files should owned by shell/system... your device policy is quite restrictive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize Application's Internal Private Storage (usually present under `/data/local/` which has explicit adb shell user access).

In your case you can do it as below.

```
# Create your file (On Host PC) #
$ touch hello.txt

# Push it to the device (If the below path doesnt exist, it will create it) #
$ adb push hello.txt /data/local/tmp
  0 KB/s (14 bytes in 0.043s)

# Switch to ADB Shell #
$ adb shell

# See Permissions before applying chmod #
shell@android:/ $ ls -l /data/local/tmp/
-rw-rw-rw- shell    shell          14 2015-07-14 15:35 hello.txt

# Change permissions using chmod # 
shell@android:/ $ chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/hello.txt

# See Permissions after applying chmod #
shell@android:/ $ ls -l data/local/tmp/
-rwxrwxrwx shell    shell          14 2015-07-14 15:35 hello.txt
```

Tested on non-rooted Android phone.

```
Android  OS : 5.0.2  
ADB version : Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
```

Refer to the comments for this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25525994/2968959)